# How to recover a repository in gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

I trying to restore a gerrit repo in prod environment.
How can I restore a repo making sure the integrity of data on disk and database  is not lost.

Please suggest something

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the git repo restoration is really gerrit-related.
However, for checking the integrity, you can let gerrit run the reindexing step which will do checks between gerrit's changes database and the git repo(s). It is sometimes necessary after gerrit version upgrades but with an offline system, you can let it run "anytime". See [docs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/pgm-reindex.html), good luck.